# PdfViewerControl in devexpress shows a white background while loading PDF file

Tags: wpf, devexpress-wpf

While loading the PDF file a white background is showed inside the control .
How to remove the white background.

This is the way i use pdf viewer control in xaml

```
<dxpdf:PdfViewerControl AsyncDocumentLoad="True" x:Name="testView" ShowOpenFileOnStartScreen="False" ShowStartScreen="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  CommandBarStyle="None"/>
```

and in code behind

```
 testView.DocumentSource = "D:\\test.pdf";
            testView.ZoomMode = DevExpress.Xpf.DocumentViewer.ZoomMode.FitToWidth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself

```
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  DispatcherPriority.Background,
  new Action(() => { testView.DocumentSource = "D:\\test.pdf"; testView.ZoomMode = DevExpress.Xpf.DocumentViewer.ZoomMode.FitToWidth; }));
```